# How do I find the intersect between the lines and sketch the lines $t\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ and $s\vec{c}+\vec{d}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

When $\vec{a}=(1,1), \vec{b}=(2,-1), \vec{c}=(2,0),$ and $\vec{d}=(1,-3)$ How do I sketch this?

Comment: Show us your workings, what have you tried? Posting direct question without showing that you've tried something it's not very well seen on this site!

Comment: I did this for the intersect: We can get the following:$2+t=1+2s$ and $-1+t=-3$. Now we can use this to find $t=-2$ and then $2+-2=1+2s\Rightarrow s=-\frac{1}{2}$. Thus the intersect $p=-2(1,1)+(2,-1)=(0,-3)$

But I am not really sure how to sketch this out. I am also doing this on LaTex so the sketching is particularly difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines will intersect at the values $t^\ast$ and $s^\ast$ satisfying $t^\ast\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b} = s^\ast \mathbf{c} +\mathbf{d}$. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ this can be written as the system of equations
$$
t^\ast a_0 + b_0 = s^\ast c_0 + d_0\\
t^\ast a_1 + b_1 = s^\ast c_1 + d_1
$$
where I'm using the convention $\mathbf{x} = (x_0,x_1)$. You now have two equations with two unknowns.

As for sketching a graph, if you have the equation $t\, \mathbf{m} + \mathbf{b}$, then the line passes through $\mathbf{b}$ (setting $t = 0$) and heads "in the direction" of $\mathbf{m}$. (If you draw the vector $\mathbf{m}$ emanating from the point $\mathbf{b}$, that will look like a line segment of the full line).

Comment: Why are we setting $t=0$? I was under the impression that it was equal to 2.

Comment: In the line $t\,\mathbf{m}+\mathbf{b}$, if $t = 0$, then we are left with $\mathbf{b}$, which shows us that the line passes through the point $\mathbf{b}$. The variable $t$ itself is a "dummy" variable since the line is actually the set $\{ t\,\mathbf{m} + \mathbf{b} \mid t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: so then we know that the line passes through $(2,-1)$ with a slope of $t$? How do we solve for $m$?

Answer (score 1):

To sketch it, mark the point $b$ on your page.  Then draw a vector from $b$ in the direction of $a.$

Now make a line in this direction through $b.$

Do the same thing creating a line through d in the direction of $c.$

There are many ways to solve this.  As others have point out how to evaluate the parameters.  Another way would be to derive the standard equations of the lines.

$x-y =3\\
y = -3$